# How to compare ruby hash with same key?

Tags: ruby

I have two hashes like this:

```
hash1 = Hash.new
hash1["part1"] = "test1"
hash1["part2"] = "test2"
hash1["part3"] = "test3"

hash2 = Hash.new
hash2["part1"] = "test1"
hash2["part2"] = "test2"
hash2["part3"] = "test4"
```

Expected output: `part3`

Basically, I want to iterate both of the hashes and print out `"part3"` because the value for `"part3"` is different in the hash. I can guarantee that the keys for both hashes will be the same, the values might be different. I want to print out the keys when their values are different?

I have tried iterating both hashes at once and comparing values but does not seem to give the right solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages and "[mcve]". We'd like to see evidence of your effort. Currently it looks like you haven't tried and are asking us to write the code for you. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421 is a useful read.

Answer (score 3):

The cool thing about Ruby is that it is so high level that it is often basically English:

> Print keys from the first hash if the values in the two hashes are different:

```
hash1.keys.each { |key| puts key if hash1[key] != hash2[key] }
```

> Select the first hash keys that have different values in the two hashes and print each of them:

```
hash1.keys.select { |key| hash1[key] != hash2[key] }.each { |key| puts key }
```

Comment: How about just `puts hash1.keys.select { |key| hash1[key] != hash2[key] } # prints "part3"`?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I'll leave this should it be of interest, but @ndn's solution is certainly better.

```
p hash1.merge(hash2) { |_,v1,v2| v1==v2 }.reject { |_,v| v }.keys
  # ["part3"]

hash1["part1"] = "test99"
p hash1.merge(hash2) { |_,v1,v2| v1==v2 }.reject { |_,v| v }.keys
  # ["part1", "part3"]
```

This uses the form of Hash#merge that employs a block (here `{ |_,v1,v2| v1==v2 }`) to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. See the doc for an explanation of the three block variables, `_`, `v1` and `v2`. The first block variable equals the common key. I've used the local variable `_` for that, as is customary when the variable is not used in the block calculation.

The steps (for the original `hash1`):

```
g = hash1.merge(hash2) { |_,v1,v2| v1==v2 }
  #=> {"part1"=>true, "part2"=>true, "part3"=>false} 
h = g.reject { |_,v| v }
  #=> {"part3"=>false} 
h.keys
  #=> ["part3"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way is that of ndn, here a solution without blocks by converting to arrays, joining them and subtracting the elements that are the same, followed by converting back to hash and asking for the keys.

Next time it would be better to include what you tried so far.

```
((hash1.to_a + hash2.to_a) - (hash1.to_a & hash2.to_a)).to_h.keys
# ["part3"]
```